# android 6.0 kernel log time is error

Tags: android

in android 6.0:
kernel log had add to logd, but usually, the time is error, display utc time and less or bigger than the main log time. in the case,cannot get the correct time flow.

not correct:

```
06-22 20:48:06.711353  1588  1732 D PowerManagerService:
06-22 20:48:06.712008  1588  1732 D PowerManagerService:
06-22 20:48:06.712350  1588  1732 D PowerManagerService:
06-22 20:48:06.712401  1588  1588 I power_screen_state: 
06-22 20:48:06.712532  1588  1732 D PowerManagerService:
02-07 18:18:09.498092     0     0 I [ 1647.613250]: [06-
02-07 18:18:09.499499     0     0 W [ 1647.614657][06-22
02-07 18:18:09.499503     0     0 W [ 1647.614661][06-22

after correction:


06-22 20:52:54.027133  1567  2032 D PowerManagerService: 
updateUserActivitySummaryLocked: mWak
06-22 20:52:54.027230  1567  2032 D PowerManagerService: updateDisplayPowerStateLocked: mDispl
06-22 20:52:54.027439  1567  2032 D PowerManagerService: Acquiring suspend blocker "PowerManag
06-22 20:52:54.038956  1567  1567 D AlarmManager: set alarm to RTC 3 ,      when = 180943
06-22 20:52:50.905602     0     0 W [   97.905672] healthd: battery l=100(3404) v=4388 t=31.7 
06-22 20:52:50.918677     0     0 I [   97.918747] : done.                            
06-22 20:52:54.035200     0     0 I [   97.920799] PM: suspend exit 2016-06-22 12:52:54.035200
06-22 20:52:54.047675   567  2254 V audio_hw_primary: is_supported_swapping_dev, not supported
```

the kernel time still not correct.

whether have another way to correct the time?